# Docusign API to update existing user email address

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a docusign API, SOAP or REST or both, that will let me update the email address of an existing user/member?  I cannot seem to find one which makes me think its not possible, but hoping that is not true.  Our users occasionally change email addresses, and i dont want to have to create new users for them everytime they update their email address.

Comment: No there is not, they can use the console to change their address only.

Answer (score 0):

/login_information/email
{
  "email": "String content", 
}

This will initiate a "change email" activation email to the current email address.  The new email address will not be committed to the membership until the activation link is clicked.